# Rails | How to target Invalid Input fields with Tailwind

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

This is annoying because I feel like I have tried everything. My goal is to have a red ring around invalid input fields when the input is invalid. How do I target invalid input fields in rails 6. I am using a rails form which is generated by devise. I am also using tailwind css.

I have tried all of the following.

```
.invalid{
   @apply ring-2 ring-red-700
}
```

```
.input:invalid{
    @apply ring-2 ring-red-700
}
```

```
.input-group {

    .invalid {
        @apply ring-2 ring-red-700
    }
}
```

Here is the form I am using to register users

```
<% content_for :devise_form do %>
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name),  :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, 
                          autofocus: true, 
                          autocomplete: "email", 
                          class: "input",
                          placeholder: "Your Email"%>
      </div>
      
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, 
                              autocomplete: "current-password", 
                              class: "input"%>
                              
      </div>
    
      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-default loader" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    
    <hr class="mt-6 border" />
    
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<% end %>  
<%= render "devise/shared/form_wrapper" %>
```

So how do I target fields whose input's are invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the developer tools in the browser. I inspected the element which is called input#user_password.invalid. So the long term solution is to use inspect elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
@layer components {
  .field_with_errors { @apply border-2 border-red-700}
}
```